connect alembic to Cloud SQL with google connector
I connected my fastapi project to Cloud SQL by following this code in this link 1
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.engine import Engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from google.cloud.sql.connector import Connector

# helper function to return SQLAlchemy connection pool
def init_connection_pool(connector: Connector) -> Engine:
    # Python Connector database connection function
    def getconn():
        conn = connector.connect(
            "project:region:instance-name", # Cloud SQL Instance Connection Name
            "pg8000",
            user="my-user",
            password="my-password",
            db="my-database",
            ip_type="public"  # "private" for private IP
        )
        return conn

    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "postgresql+pg8000://"

    engine = create_engine(
        SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL , creator=getconn
    )
    return engine

# initialize Cloud SQL Python Connector
connector = Connector()

# create connection pool engine
engine = init_connection_pool(connector)

# create SQLAlchemy ORM session
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()

I would like to follow the same to connect alembic to the Cloud SQL. As far as I know I should set the sqlalembic.url in alembic.ini file. I did not document how to connect with google connector. Is there a way?
I run the cloud-sql-proxy PROJECT_NAME:REGIN:SQLDB and I can work fine with the project.
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector/blob/main/README.md

Does this answer your question? How to connect Google cloud SQL with alembic

no, it also try to set the url ("mysql+pymysql://db_user:db_pass@db_host:db_port/db_name"). I would like to follow the same. I used google connector. I am trying to avoid two different approaches in one code.

You're on the right track! You can leverage the existing code for your FastAPI project to connect Alembic to Cloud SQL using the Google Cloud SQL Python Connector. I'll post an answer in a bit.

Here's the gist of connecting Alembic to Cloud SQL using the Google Cloud SQL Python Connector:

alembic.ini:

Set sqlalchemy.url with the connection string format:



    postgresql+pg8000://{user}:{password}@localhost:{port}/{database}


Replace placeholders with your Cloud SQL credentials and details.

localhost points to the cloud-sql-proxy running locally.



Optional: Reuse Connection Pool (env.py):

Import init\_connection\_pool from your FastAPI project's utils.
Use the returned engine object from init\_connection\_pool.


Cloud SQL Proxy:

Run cloud-sql-proxy with the correct parameters:



./cloud-sql-proxy --address=0.0.0.0 --port=1234 <project>:<region>:<instance-name>

Remember:

Use environment variables for sensitive information.

localhost in the connection string points to the local cloud-sql-proxy.


Reference:

Cloud SQL Python Connector README

Connecting to Cloud SQL for PostgreSQL

Alembic Configuration



The question is how I can use google connector instead of setting simple sqlalchemy.url in the alembic.ini.
The project connects to the Could Sql db with connector and I would like to connect alembic with connector and not set a simple url in alembic.ini.
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-python-connector?tab=readme-ov-file#fastapi

Inside Alembic's env.py, you can swap out the default engine with your Google Cloud custom engine from cloud-sql-python-connector.
If you do not wish to run it from the command line, you may call its migration API inside your application like this
def db_upgrade():
alembic_cfg = Config("alembic.ini")
with engine.begin() as connection:
    alembic_cfg.attributes['connection'] = connection
    command.upgrade(alembic_cfg, "head")

Source 1
Source 2
